# не отрабатывает timeout в bash скрипте

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unix

команда отрабатывает:

```
timeout 10s sh WGET.sh example.com  2>&1 >/dev/null | ./a.out > example.com.log.txt
```

а вот если ее поместить в скрип `test.sh` и запустить `sh test.sh`, то `WGET.sh` вроде перестает работать, но из скрипта не выходит

Comment: wget - отдает информацию в stderr, что по умолчанию 2-й дескриптор, данное выражение перенаправляет в пайп данные со 2-го дескриптора, а с 1-го соответственно в /dev/null, это я на хабре подсмотрел ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ну у меня получилось запустить через третий скрипт: `timeout 10s sh my.sh`

Comment: я не силен в bash скриптах и не смогу объяснить, но по факту получается, что я передаю stderr(непустой) другому процессу на его stdin, что мне и нужно было сделать